# Wordpress - search in single category

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a search page and I need an option to retrieve all results in a single category only. The categories are for custom post types. In a normal result it returns all the matching result and also shows category. When I add `&cat=5` to the link as suggested, it always return empty result. I've tried really simple searches by a single letter and it normally should retrieve a lot of post results, however, it seems not to be working. How can I specify the category here?

Comment: can you display your wp_query?

Comment: It's the default search query, I am not changing there anything.